# Change Metabox Title

Tags: metabox

Anyone know of a way to change the title of the core Wordpress metaboxes on a post edit screen? I'm trying to alter the title of the "Featured Image" metabox and have found a way to edit the contents (via *admin_post_thumbnail_html*) but not the title itself.

Answer (score 2):

The "Right way" to do this is hooking to the 'add_meta_boxes' action, like so:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_metabox_titles', 10, 2);
function my_metabox_titles($post_type, $post) {
    global $wp_meta_boxes; // array of defined metaboxes
    // cycle through the array, change the titles you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you like things to work without js, you can provide your own text for ALL translateable text.

Basically create translations for the text you want to change.  Non-english speakers do it all the time - it's not that hard.

See http://icalevents.com/3445-an-accent-for-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

you can change it by filtered words like it :

```
<?php 

add_filter('gettext', 'mw_translate_words_array');

add_filter('ngettext', 'mw_translate_words_array');

function mw_translate_words_array( $translated ) {
$words = array(
 'old name' = > 'new name'  ,
);

$translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
return $translated;
}
?>
```